# How to find CDF of PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

i'm doing exercise (i'm a student) for probability and there is something that I don't understand, How do we manage to find bound of $CDF$ given a $PDF$.

the PDF : $f(x,y) = k$ , is obviously uniformly distributed have the constraint of $0<x<y<1$.

well we know that $\int_{}^{}\int_{}^{}f(x,y)dydx = 1$

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1}kdydx = 1$

$k/2 = 1$ then $k = 2$ we can verify that $k = 2$ by integrating the functions in all of it's domains and it is giving $1$

When I want to find the CDF I do this :

$\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y} 2dvdu = \int_{0}^{x} 2y du = 2xy$

I know that i'm wrong because $x$ and $y$ are dependant each other and here i'm counting also the part where where $x>y$ but I dont know to bound the integrals to respect the dependance. I followed the formula of a CDF given PDF : $F(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{y} f(u,v)dvdu$

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: In the given formula I think it is implied that whenever we are out of our "definition interval" the function $f(u,v)$ is set to be zero. So really you are integrating
$$\int_{\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y 2 \cdot \chi_{0<x<y<1} dv du$$
with the characteristic funtion of your given "definition interval". That would leave us with the integral
$$\int_0^x \int_u^y 2 dv du$$

Comment: @Lukas thank you for you comment I understand better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint cdf is given by

$P(X\leq u,Y\leq v)$ . As $f(x,y)>0$ for $x<y<1$. We have to look at whether $u<v$ or $u>v$ and separate the cases .

if $u\geq v$ . Then

$P(X\leq u, Y\leq v) = P(X\leq v, Y\leq v) = \int_{0}^{v}\int_{0}^{y}2\,dx\,dy=v^{2}$.

If $u<v$ . Then we have $P(X\leq u,Y\leq v)=2(uv-\frac{1}{2}u^{2})$

So $$F(x,y)= \begin{cases} y^{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{x\geq y,\,0\leq y\leq 1\}}\\2(xy-\frac{x^{2}}{2})\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{x<y,\,0\leq y\leq1\}}\\2(x-\frac{x^{2}}{2})\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{y>1\,,\,0\leq x\leq 1\}}\\1\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x>1,y>1\}} \\0,\,\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, If I understand well in my case we are only interested with $u < v$ , right ?

Comment: Not really. The probability that $P(X<u,Y<v)$ is not zero just because $u>v$. It's true that the pdf will be zero outside that region. But here we are trying to calculate the probability that $P(X<u,Y<v)=P(X<v,Y<v)$. For example I know that $P(2<X<3,0<Y<1)$ is zero. But that does not mean $P(X<3,Y<1)$ is zero. because $P(X<1,Y<1)$ is positive.

Comment: Ohh ok I understand now, thank you Gandalf :)

Comment: Just try and draw the graph and just find the areas of the intersecting regions. and then multiply by $2$. That way it will be clear

Comment: But @BilalBrarou . Just write the cdf a bit more carefully , I was reckless with the notations. Just take care and mention the regions clearly.